# Access Required Response from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Going by the [code provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) (I'm assuming), I am unable to query my Azure Active Directory.  Every time I call the following, I get a response of `{Authorization Required.}`:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedCollection = await client.Users.ExecuteAsync();
```

I'm new to Azure Active Directory and I'm new to the Graph and thought that the samples provided would function.  They do not and I am hoping someone here can tell me either what is wrong with the code or how do I grant myself authorization to my own directory?  I thought the AccessKey would be the authentication method, but apparently that's useless as it's not used in their examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, to call the REST which protected by Azure AD which support OAuth2.0 to authorize the third-party application, we need to pass a bearer token.

And to go through the code sample, please ensure that you followed the steps list by the README.md.

Note: there is something not clear in the README.md about config the permission. The code sample is using the **Azure AD Graph** instead of Microsoft Graph, we need to choose the **Windows Azure Active Directory** instead of **Microsoft Graph**. And I have report this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/issues/41).

You can see that there is a static filed named **token** in class AuthenticationHelper which will be set the value when the users sign-in using the code in Startup.Auth.cs like below:( not using cert)

```
// Create a Client Credential Using an Application Key
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                                    code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

AuthenticationHelper.token = result.AccessToken;
```

And here is the detail progress to acquire the token via the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow:
[image]

More detail about this flow you can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/).